# Prefered keystroke for ending NSTextView edit

Tags: macos, cocoa, keyboard-shortcuts, nstextview

Is there prefered keystroke for ending edit of an NSTextVIew?  Obvious candidates are ESCape and Return with modifier key.  I'd like this to be fairly intuitive and easy to type.  Of course for people raised on Vim, Escape is the obvious choice.

Since I mentioned Vim, I thought I'd add my emacsish version:
For emacs I guess it might be C-x C-S.  I would find this more convenient typing than ESC. But what would be the cocoa way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> is quite common for confirming multi-line input (this is used for example in Apple's iWork when editing a text frame).

In standard Cocoa text views, <kbd>Esc</kbd> triggers auto-completion suggestions (when applicable).

Comment: I like this, since there is precedent.  I confirmed on the Apple support Pages shortcuuts page.  I never could have found this since I don't use iwork.

Answer (score 0):

**<kbd>tab</kbd> is the most popular to switch between different textfields and textviews and is considered as end of editing.**

Also you can use any combination as per your likings, e.g. <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> etc to move out of the textView.

But no to <kbd>esc</kbd>, it sends as something you are cancelling. However this is used in CUI as vim, but surely not in GUI for OSX and even for Windows.

Comment: As far as I know, your answer applies to NSTextField.  I'm interested in NSTextView.  In NSTextView one often writes long documents, and uses return for newline.  Most apps I know, you mouse out of the NSTExtView or menu out to end editing.  I would like to do this with keystrokes. I know of one soon-to-be-released app that uses ESCAPE, but I believe the default use of escape in NSTextView is to give spelling information.

Comment: OOPssss... yes I dint notice textView.